# Is their a way to regenerate the push notification token manually (iOS, Android, Windows)

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, apple-push-notifications

I have a use case where I want to regenerate a new push notification token programmatically on (iOS, Android, Windows). Is their a way to do the same, I am not able to find any such API's.

Answer (score 1):

as per what i recall ios u cant regenrate the token.. once generated it remains the same for the app.. its a combination of bluetooth id+ app+wifi id etc... so cant regenrate it to get a new token....Google with time the token changes after a set time

Answer (score 1):

You cannot regenerate the Token, it stays the same after it has been created.

If you have lost your token you can request it again and you recieve the same token that you got the first time.

You can kind of regenerate the token on windowsphone by changing something in the application then reinstalling it onto your phone. So you could technicly make some unused lines of code then reinstall it and you should get a new ID. I have not tested this on IOS/Android but i know it works on Windowsphone 8.1.